# A local explanation of the CHSH game

Tags: quantum-mechanics, foundations

I have read lots of papers claiming that we can get rid of nonlocality in QM using some interpretations like consistent histories. For example, Griffiths deduces the same violation of Bell's inequalities by separating the beam of Neon atoms into four beams and doing local measurements on them, as you can see here:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.07050

I have no problem with the derivation in the case of violating the said Bell's inequality.

However, in the CHSH game, the measurements done are determined by random number generators, on distant particles, so how such a splitting of the beam can even work? How does that enable us to get rid of nonlocality?

Answer (score 1):

Griffiths replaces the CHSH experiment, in which measurements happen at spacelike separated locations, with a different experiment in which all measurements happen at the same location, and he argues on that basis that "[n]onlocality is irrelevant" to CHSH violation.

Ignoring the CHSH experiment and analyzing a different, less interesting experiment does nothing to counter the nonlocality argument based on the original experiment, as you said. I have no idea what point he was trying to make here.

The rest of the paper is just as mystifying to me. He seems to be saying that to derive an inequality that contradicts experiments you have to make classical assumptions, and if you make quantum assumptions instead then there's no difficulty in explaining the experiments. That's true, but I think it was obvious to everyone from the beginning.

Comment: Exactly. After all, if quantum mechanics is truly nonlocal, then the inequalities will be violated no matter how much is the distance separating the particles (whether it's light years or zero), and the experiment he's suggesting is when the distance is zero, but that's irrelevant. This is why I cannot see how it could be used to counter nonlocality. What baffles me is that all academic literature that I have read about consistent histories say that it's local, a claim that I cannot reconcile with the CHSH game, and I am afraid that I have some blind spot that I cannot see.